# Is there any compatibility issues with magento 1.5 and PHP 5.4

Tags: upgrade, magento-1.5, php-5.4

I have a Magento 1.5 site and PHP 5.3 version.I want to upgrade the PHP version to 5.4.Is there any compatibility issues will occur with magento 1.5? Is magento 1.5 support PHP version 5.4 ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that Magento 1.5 is compatible with PHP 5.4.
According to http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/php54-patch, there is a Patch solving problems with Magento 1.6.0.0–1.8.1.0.

If you want to use PHP 5.4, you should consider about updating the Magento-Code or try to test it in another enviroment.

Cheers,
Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris.We will thinks about to upgrade the magento

Answer (score 0):

Magento is still patching in PHP 5.4 support. If you want the best experience in this regard, always got with the very latest version. Right now this should be 1.9.1.0.

You can easily test your own shop by enabling magento developer mode. It should display all sort of errors incl. strict warnings which you most likely will trigger with PHP 5.4 (and later on 5.5).

But as others have written, it's better you move up to a more recent version of magento.